# How does the cassandra know that it has completed QUORUM?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have always used Cassandra in spark applications, but I never wondered how it works internally. Reading the Cassandra documentation I got a small doubt (which may be a beginner's doubt).
I read in a book (Cassandra The Definitive Guide) and in the official Cassandra documentation that the formula would be:
(RF / 2) + 1.

So theoretically if I have a cluster with 6 nodes, and a replication factor of 3, I would only need response from 2 nodes.

And here come the small doubts:
1 - What would this response be? (The query return with the data?)
2 - If there was no data with the filters used in the query, is the empty return considered a response?
3 - And last but not least, if the empty return is considered a response, if these two nodes that complete the QUORUM don't have the replica data yet, my application that did the SELECT will understand that this data doesn't exist in the database, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1 - What would this response be? (The query return with the data?)*

The coordinator node will wait for 2 replicas of the 3 (because CL=QUORUM) to respond to the query (with the request results). It will then send the response to the client.

*2 - If there was no data with the filters used in the query, is the empty return considered a response?*

Yes, the empty response will be sufficient and will be considered a valid response. Note that there is a mechanism last-write-wins (based on row write time) used in case of conflict.

*3 - And last but not least, if the empty return is considered a response, if these two nodes that complete the QUORUM don't have the replica data yet, my application that did the SELECT will understand that this data doesn't exist in the database, right?*

You have to understand that Apache Cassandra uses eventual consistency meaning that the client will decide on the desired CL. If you have a strong consistency, meaning you have an overlap of the write CL and read CL (**Write CL + Read CL > RF**), then will always retrieve the last data. I recommend you to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx-pmH-b5mI

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning sounds correct to me.
Basically, if you're reading at LOCAL_QUORUM and have an RF of 3, it's possible that the coordinator accepts a response from two replicas that are both inconsistent and leaves out the third replica that had consistent data.

It's one of the reasons Cassandra is considered an eventually consistent db, and also why regular repairs of the data are so important for production databases.  Of course, if consistency mattered above all else, you could always read with a CL of ALL, but you'd sacrifice some amount of response time as a tradeoff.  Assuming the db is provisioned well though, while it's certainly in the realm of possible, it isn't likely that only a single replica receives an incoming write unless you make a habit an only writing at a CL of ONE/LOCAL_ONE.  If consistency mattered, you'd be writing to the db with a CL of at least LOCAL_QUORUM to avoid this very scenario.

To try and answer your questions directly, yes, having no data to return can be a valid response, and yes if the two replicas chosen by the coordinator both agree there is no data to return, the app will report that result.